# Validator returns an incorrect value

Tags: angular

I have a problem with display correct value in my validator. My validator check if  after entering in the form field the given "username" already exists in the database.
 
Now it doesn't work correctly. For example: username -> abc exists in the database returns incorrect value: "UserName is available!" and returns to non-existent value " UserNamme is taken!". 

 
My backend response return correct value (true if exists or false otherwise). I think the problem is in the custom validator in Angular.

**My service in angular:**

```
  TakeUsernameIfExist(username): Promise<boolean> {
      return this.http.get<boolean>(this.rootUrl + '/api/TakeUserName/' + username ).toPromise();  
}
```

**Register component:**

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formInitBuilder();
  }

  formInitBuilder() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group ({
      UserName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required], this.validateUserNameTaken.bind(this)),
      Password: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
      Email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      FirstName: new FormControl(),
      LastName: new FormControl()
    });

}
// Validator
validateUserNameTaken(control: AbstractControl) {
  return this.userService.TakeUsernameIfExist(control.value).then(res => {
    return res ? null : { userName : true };
  });

}
onSubmit(form: FormGroup) {
  if (form.valid) {
  this.userService.registerUser(form.value).
   subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data.Succeeded === true) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
     }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('error');
  }
}
}`
```

**HTML template:**

```
<form class="main-form needs-validation"  [formGroup]="form"  >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="UserName" formControlName="UserName" required>
        <div *ngIf="form.get('UserName').status === 'PENDING'">
          Checking...
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="form.get('UserName').status === 'VALID'">
           UserName is available!
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="form.get('UserName').errors && form.get('UserName').errors['userName']">
          UserNamme is taken!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**And Wep API:**

```
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("api/TakeUserName/{username}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> TakeUserName(string username) 
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

            var result = await  userStore.FindByNameAsync(username);
          return (result == null )  ? Ok(false) : Ok( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.UserName));

        }
```

Any help or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: If you add a console log in `validateUserNameTaken`, does it log the correct value?

Comment: seems like your ternanry operator needs to reverse. if user exist (true), validator should return { userName : true}, else return null.

Comment: Thank you @SureshKumarAriya. Now it working correctly.

Comment: @kamil To elaborate: when a validator returns `null`, it means it's valid.